# Where was Goren H'Atad physically located?

Tags: geography, vayechi

Where was the place referred to in Bereshis 50:10 as Goren H'Atad physically located? Is it the name of another city?

Comment: Try looking at the [דעת מקרא](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Da%27at_Miqra) Chumash; I don't have one with me, at the moment.

Comment: http://etzion.org.il/en/parashat-vayechi-goren-ha-atad has some in depth analysis

Answer (score 6):

[Chidushei Yitzchak ben Pinchas](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=32311&st=&pgnum=20&hilite=) says that there were two locations known as Goren H'atad. One was in the Western part of Eretz Yisrael near where the Philistines were at the edge of the Yam HaGadol. The other was in the Eastern part of Eretz Yisrael near Chevron next to the Yarden, which is the location the Chumash is talking about.