# Did Jacob's sons do aveilut before Jacob was buried?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, mourning-aveilus, vayechi

In viewing [Breishit 50:10](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=662) it says that the group came to *Goren Ha'atad* and they made a seven-day mourning period for their father there.

Only afterwards, does it state that they buried Jacob in the Cave of Machpela.

Currently, the 7 day period of mourning follows the burial. Was Jacob an exception or was the practice different then compared to what current *halacha* is? Why was the mourning before burial? Would that have been considered the equivalent of our *shiva* period, or was that something else that we no longer do?

Comment: I don't see any clear proof from the verses what the order was. After discussing the great mourning period, it goes back and summarizes the whole venture.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/52797/759 as understanding the geography can possibly help understand the timeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a people who suggest that Yosef and his brothers were accompanied by a large group of Egyptions. These Egyptians were the "official delegation" who were accompanying Yosef. Reading the description, we see that this is more like a military operation and as such would not be allowed to actually enter another country. Yosef and his brothers on the other hand continued on to Chevron to put Yaakov in *Mearas hamachpelah*. As a result, they stopped at the place where the Egyptians broke off and mourned Yaakov there before the continuation.

Professor [Yoel Elitzur](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%95%D7%90%D7%9C_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8_(%D7%97%D7%95%D7%A7%D7%A8_%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%94%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA)) cites his father, Professor [Yehuda Elitzur](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%99%D7%94%D7%95%D7%93%D7%94_%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8), in [Parashat Vayechi: Goren Ha-atad](http://etzion.org.il/en/parashat-vayechi-goren-ha-atad) with a similar answer, but states that the Egyptian military delegation had another purpose.

> We read here that the delegation of mourners for Jacob consisted of
>   chariots and horsemen, “a very large troop.” The scope of this journey
>   seems to more closely resemble that of a military operation than that
>   of a mourners’ procession. If we analyze the verses carefully, we will
>   see that the delegation was actually comprised of two separate groups.
>   One group consisted of Jacob’s family: “Joseph’s household, his
>   brothers and his father’s household.” The second group consisted of
>   “the officials of Pharaoh, the senior members of his court and all of
>   Egypt’s dignitaries,” and with them, chariots and horsemen – a very
>   large troop. In other words, it is a small group of Israelites
>   traveling alongside a large Egyptian delegation. A close reading of
>   the verses demonstrates that, following the mourning ceremony in Goren
>   Ha-atad, Jacob’s sons alone proceeded on to bury their father: “His
>   sons did for him as he had instructed them. His sons carried him to
>   the land of Canaan, and buried him in the cave of the field of
>   Machpelah, the field near Mamre, which Abraham had bought” (50:12-13).
>
> What perhaps seemed like a joint procession of Egyptians and
>   Israelites was actually two separate delegations traveling alongside
>   each other for the first leg of the journey. The Torah lingers on the
>   actions of Jacob’s sons, as well as on the large portion of the
>   journey that was dedicated to mourning for Jacob. However, it seems
>   very likely that the Egyptian delegation that set out to bury Jacob
>   actually had an ulterior motive for its journey. While they certainly
>   had great respect for Jacob – they “bewailed him seventy days” (50:3)
>   and embalmed him as they would their most respected figures – the
>   journey seems to have had a different purpose as well.
>
> According to Egyptian sources, Egypt ruled over the land of Canaan
>   during that period. To maintain their hold on the land, the Egyptians
>   would set up garrisons in various locations. The most important of
>   these garrisons were located in Beit She’an and Gaza, and each year
>   the soldiers manning these garrisons would be replaced with fresh
>   troops. Apparently, this yearly changing of the guard would be
>   accompanied by a large military delegation.

Professor Elitzur thus concludes:

> To summarize, our parasha describes a large-scale Egyptian military
>   expedition, a yearly operation that involved numerous chariots and
>   horsemen. The purpose of this expedition was to replace the troops
>   manning the Egyptian garrisons throughout Canaan with fresh soldiers
>   from Egypt.
>
> Before each group of soldiers went off to their respective garrisons,
>   the delegation stopped at a central location – Goren Ha-atad – for
>   seven days, to mourn the loss of Jacob, the father of the
>   second-in-command of Egypt. After this ceremony, the Egyptian troops
>   all traveled to their designated garrisons, and Jacob’s twelve sons
>   departed for Hebron to bury their father.